# Usage of »zum« and »um zu«

Tags: difference, sentence-structure, conjunction, infinitive, nominalization

I understand that *zu* is part of the infinitive construction in German, and I also understand that *um … zu* is the English equivalent of *in order to*, specifically expressing purpose. I’m trying to make sense of the differences between the following examples, and I have a couple of questions:

> Er sucht einen guten Platz zum Essen.
>
> Wir müssen einen besseren Platz zum Fußball spielen finden.
>
> Wir müssen einen besseren Platz finden, um mit unserer Band zu üben.

I guess my first question would be: why is *zum* used in the first and second sentences instead of *zu*?

Secondly, would the following two sentences be grammatically correct and have the same meaning as the original two?

> Wir müssen einen besseren Platz finden, um Fußball zu spielen.
>
> Wir müssen einen besseren Platz um mit unserer Band zu üben finden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note some of your examples use infinitives used as substantives, while others use plain infinitives:

> Wir suchen einen guten Platz zum Essen

Uses an infinitive as a substantiated verb - It is used like a substantive ("das Essen"). It uses "zum" which is a shortened form of "zu dem", a contraction of a conjunction ("zu") with a dative article ("dem").

The same form, used with a "plain substantive" would be

> Wir suchen einen guten Platz zum Picknick.

A very literal translation to English would be

> We are looking for a good place for eating

On the other hand,

> Wir suchen einen guten Platz, um zu essen

uses a *plain infinitive*, but doesn't use it as a substantive - It needs to use the conjunction "um" and "zu" to *signal* the infinitive.

Here a very literal translation to English would be

> We are looking for a good place to eat.

Differences in meaning? No, not that I could see.

Answer (score 4):

So, first of all, the last sentence is not correct:

> <s>Wir müssen einen besseren Platz um mit unserer Band zu üben finden</s>.

Now let's see what this sentence exactly means:

> Wir müssen einen besseren Platz finden, um Fußball zu spielen.

This means *We have to find a better place in order to play football, otherwise we cannot play football at all*. Whereas:

> Wir müssen einen besseren Platz zum Fußballspielen finden. *(please note that we write Fußballspielen without a space)*

means: *We have to find a better place where we can play football, but the place where we're now would probably also do*.

Why? Saying *um zu* express purpose, as you said. For example *Ich muss schwimmen lernen, um im Notfall nicht zu ertrinken.* The *zu* is (in this case) more like English *for*:

> Platz zum Spielen --> place for playing
>
> Raum zum Lesen --> room for reading / reading room
>
> eine angenehme Straße zum Joggen --> a nice street for jogging

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience the difference between the "*um zu*" and the "*zum*" is not as important as the position within the sentence.

If the "reason" is **not** located directly **after the noun** ("*Platz*") the "reason" refers to the whole sentence:

> Wir müssen einen besseren **Platz** finden, **um Fußball zu spielen**.
>
> **Zum Fußballspielen** müssen wir einen besseren **Platz** finden.

I'm not 100% sure about the official "Hochdeutsch" but in the dialect I speak both sentences have absolutely the same meaning:

The construction explains why something is or has to be done: Another place has to be found because you want to play football.

When the "*zum*" construction however is placed **directly after the noun** the meaning changes:

> Wir müssen einen besseren **Platz zum Fußballspielen** finden.

In this case the construction "*zum Fußballspielen*" does not refer to the whole sentence but to the noun ("*Platz*"): It describes what kind of place has to be found. It does not (explicitly) give a reason why such a place must be found.

In the dialect spoken here I sometimes heared constructions like these:

> Wir müssen einen besseren **Platz, um Fußball zu spielen,** finden.
>
> Wir müssen einen besseren **Platz** finden **zum Fußballspielen**.

I'm **not sure** if these constructions are allowed in "official" German (and if yes: if the commas are correct) or if they are only used in dialect.

In the first case the "*um Fußball zu spielen*" is placed directly after the nown. Therefore it is a description of the place.

In the second case the "*zum Fußball spielen*" is not placed directly after the noun but the word "*finden*" is separating the noun from the construction. Therefore the construction refers to the whole sentence.

Theoretically you may even combine both cases - however most Germans would use "*um zu*" in this case because using "*zum*" twice in one sentence sounds wrong:

> **Zum Toreschießen** müssen wir einen besseren **Platz zum Fußballspielen** finden.